# How To Call The Correct CSS

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to replicate a page http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/ onto http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/new-refurb-publish/ but it can't get the images at the top to align correctly.
They call a div id 'outer' for the sizing but it appears correctly on te home page and not on the new page.
How can I change it so it calls the correct code on the new page without messing up the original page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have different templates in WordPress for the home and for other pages. But withou any hint of code I can't help. Also you might check the [dedicated WordPress Q&A site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress adds a series of utilities classes to your `<body>` tag; in your case the CSS targets `.home #outer` while the second page you linked is not the home page and is added other css classes. In order to make this work, you can change your css (`style.css::976`) selector from

```
.home #outer
```

to

```
.page #outer
```

this will target both your pages (as your home gets the `page` class as well). You can decide a different selector, perhaps just `#outer`, if you want to make sure that it will work also on articles.

That really depends on your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Basically I am creating a few internal pages for refurbishment etc and I want to change the page to have the 2 images at the top. The problem is the template actually covers the bottom of the page only as this is how the web designers did it. Its all a bit confusing. Unfortunately changing the css style to .page didnt work so still trying to figure out what needs to be done.

Comment: Looking at the site it seems you have figured it out. Am I correct or you still need some help?

Answer (score 0):

Images have a diffrent class applied to them, causing resizing issue and the div is 600px instead of 400. I would change the page template to match all used classes/ids for all elements and make sure they are the same for both the homepage and this subpage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem is we created a duplicate template just changing the bottom of the page. However, even when we select the home page template it still has the issues with the alignment of the top 2 images.